# psycopg2 partial identifier

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, psycopg2

```
_sql = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {prefix}_prefixed_table_name").format(prefix=sql.Identifier("prefix"))

_sql.as_string(conn)
```

Result `SELECT * FROM "prefix"_prefixed_table_name`

What I want `SELECT * FROM prefix_prefixed_table_name` or `SELECT * FROM "prefix_prefixed_table_name"`

How can I achieve this?

As a request from [klin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1995738/klin) why wouldn't

```
_sql = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {prefix}_prefixed_table_name").format(prefix=sql.SQL("prefix"))
```

work, one may simply enter

```
"another_table_name; -- "
```

which would result in

```
SELECT * FROM another_table_name; -- _prefixed_table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the table name to `Identifier()`:

```py
_sql = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {name}").format(name=sql.Identifier(prefix+ "_prefixed_table_name"))
```

Comment: Passing direct SQL doesn't protect me from SQL injection as far as I can tell.

Comment: Show an example of such an injection.

Comment: Edited the question to show an example

Comment: Ok, see the updated answer.

Comment: Now this fixes the sql injection(removed the downvote for that), but rest of the query is composed from a lot of stuff in couple of for loops, hence I need to somehow merge it in the query as magically as SQL does for trusted SQL or as Identifier does for identifiers. Still, thanks!